# Use Cayley Hamilton theorem to derive the following $(sI−A)^{-1}$ where $s \in \mathbb C$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

$(sI−A)^{-1}$  where $s\in\mathbb C$.

My attempt : I have seen this method of matrix equation using the Cayley Hamilton method .

$f(A)= (sI−A)^{-1} = h_0(I) + h_1(A)+ h_2(A)^2$;

$f(p) = h(p) = h_0 + h_1(p)+ h_2(p)^2$, where $p$ is the eigenvalues of $A$.

Given $A=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\-6&-11&-6}$ the eigenvalues are $-1,-2,-3$.

$(s - (-1))^{-1} = h_0 + h_1(-1) + h_2(-1)^2$.

$1/(s+1) = h_0 - h_1 + h_2$.

Similarly for the other two eigenvalues, and solve for $h_0,h_1,h_2$.

Is this correct? Why is $s$ given as a complex number ?

Comment: Please format the math for mathjax: click on "help" and then click on the link "How do I format math here?" - although somebody was kind enough to edit it for you, you should learn how to do it.

Comment: Can you help over this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the obverse of the actual [proof of the C-H theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#A_direct_algebraic_proof). In general,  *s* is complex because there is no guarantee your eigenvalues are real, as here.
Your method is, indeed correct.

Your characteristic polynomial is 
$$
p(s)=(s+1)(s+2)(s+3)= s^3+6s^2+11s+6 ~,
$$
and so the C-H helps you convert polynomials of higher order in *A* than quadratic to quadratic polynomials, since it dictates, here, that
$$
A^3=-6A^2-11A-6I~.
$$

Now your resolvent function *f(A)* is the *adjugate* of *sI-A* discussed in the link, divided by *p(s)*, so
$$
p(s)f(A)=(11I+6A+A^2)+s(6I+A)+s^2I = \left ( (11+6s+s^2)I + (6+s) A + A^2  \right)~ ,
$$
that is, $p(s)h_2=1$, $~p(s) h_1=6+s$, and $p(s)h_0=s^2+6s+11$.

You may check that, indeed, this quadratic polynomial is the resolvent, alright, 
$$
(sI-A) f(A)\\  
= \frac{1}{p(s)} \left( sA^2+sA(6+s) +s(11+6s+s^2)I- A^3-A^2(6+s) -A(11+6s+s^2)  \right)\\
=p(s)~I~ \frac{1}{p(s)}=I,
$$ 
where, in the second line, $A^3$ was substituted for as per the C-H theorem identity, above. As per the telescopic cancelations of the proof, all powers of *A* annihilated themselves.

And, indeed, in practical terms, it is, of course, much easier to specify the *h<sub>k</sub>* coefficients by plugging in eigenvalues, as you started doing, than 
computing the adjugate directly--I just used the efficient [Faddeev–LeVerrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm) which reverses the telescoping sum of the proof, instead. You are doing fine.